# Optional Parameters in mysql select query

Tags: c#, mysql, select, optional-parameters

I am trying to implement optional search in my project which has five input values as optional (CompanyID, PackageID, SubjectID, Fromdate and Todate)

I have written the mysql query as

```
select l.RefNo, l.LetterDate, l.CompanyID, l.Subject,
   c.CompanyID, 
   c.CompanyCode,
   p.PackageName, p.PackageID
   from tblletter l,
   tblcompany c,
   tblpackage p
        where 
        (companyID is null or l.CompanyID = companyID ) and
                     (packageID is null or l.PackageID = packageID) and
                     (subjectID is null or l.LetterID = subjectID);
```

but i am not able to get the result, and i need a syntax to send the date values as null, i have tried as

> `DateTime? fromdate=....`

Is this syntax correct?
Thank you.

updated my code to

```
select l.RefNo, l.LetterDate, l.CompanyID, l.Subject,
Case LetterType
    When 1 then 'PSK'
    When 2 then c.CompanyCode
End As FromCompany,  
Case LetterType
    When 1 then c.CompanyCode
    When 2 then 'PSK'
End As ToCompany,


 c.CompanyCode,
   p.PackageID
   from tblletter l,
   tblcompany c ,
   tblpackage p  
    where l.CompanyID = c.CompanyID and l.PackageID = p.PackageID and

    l.CompanyID Like 
        case 

            when l.CompanyID = c.CompanyID and companyID > 0 then ('%' + LTRIM(companyID) + '%')
            else '%%'
        end
and l.PackageID Like
          case 

            when l.PackageID = p.PackageID and packageID > 0 then ('%' + LTRIM(packageID) + '%')
            else '%%'
        end  
and l.Subject =
          case 
            when subjectName is not null then  subjectName
            else '%%'
        end;
```

but still getting empty table value...

```
the possible cases are
1). companyID = 30 or packageID = 0 or subjectName = null
2). companyID = 0 or packageID = 11 or subjectName = null
3). companyID = 0 or packageID = 0 or subjectName = 'sand'
4). companyID = 30 and packageID = 11 or subjectName = null
5). companyID = 30 or packageID = 0 and subjectName = 'sand'
```

here if the values is '0' it has to be ignored(OR)
so on... like ...

Comment: instead of adding optional parameters in query, try to create the query using conditions in your code, so that the final query will be having only the needed parameters\

Comment: So, do need to write five separate stored procedures  with one each parameter?? @manoj

Comment: No no, sorry, i didnt know that this is  a stored procedure, I was thinking you are firing a query directly from your c# program.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Run your query directly (e.g. in some query editor UI) first (you
   might already be doing this, but if not, it will help)
2. Use ANSI
   style join syntax to clearly separate the join criteria of the three
   tables (the `FROM` clause) from the *filter* criteria in your
   `WHERE` clause
3. Your first example, where you test the parameter
   for NULL and have an OR condition, may be simpler, since the engine
   can determine that part of the `WHERE` clause to be TRUE right away, rather            than actually testing the row values using a dummied up LIKE operator using '%%'
4. Run the query (in an editor) first with the joined tables but
   comment out the entire `WHERE` clause and make sure you see data.
   Then, start uncommenting the `WHERE` clause, piece by piece,
   including parameter values (or literals in their place), making sure
   you see the results you expect at each step. This will help narrow
   down your troubleshooting process.

Here's an example query demonstrating these ideas:

```
SELECT 
    l.RefNo, l.LetterDate, l.CompanyID, l.Subject,
    Case LetterType
        When 1 then 'PSK'
        When 2 then c.CompanyCode
    End As FromCompany,  
    Case LetterType
        When 1 then c.CompanyCode
        When 2 then 'PSK'
    End As ToCompany,
    c.CompanyCode,
    p.PackageID
FROM tblletter l
INNER JOIN tblcompany c ON l.CompanyID = c.CompanyID   --make sure whether this should be INNER or LEFT OUTER join
INNER JOIN tblpackage p ON l.PackageID = p.PackageID   --make sure whether this should be INNER or LEFT OUTER join
WHERE 1 = 1  --useful if commenting and uncommenting additional parts of WHERE clause
AND (companyID is null OR l.CompanyID = companyID) -- can do the LIKE version instead, but may be slower... test both
AND (packageID is null OR p.PackageID = packageID) -- can do the LIKE version instead, but may be slower... test both
AND (subjectName is null OR l.Subject = subjectName) -- can do the LIKE version instead, but may be slower... test both
;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ... here is the code **AND (35 is null OR l.CompanyID = 35) -- can do the LIKE version instead, but may be slower... test both
AND (0 is null OR p.PackageID = 0) -- can do the LIKE version instead, but may be slower... test both
AND (null is null OR l.Subject = null)** 
its like a value with companyID only.. but still getting empty result..

Comment: @htiru - like I put in #4 above, try running the query WITHOUT the `WHERE` clauses first, so that you can verify the table joins are working the way you expect. If you don't get data back, there is a problem in the `FROM` clause. If you do get data, you can start adding in filters (your `WHERE` clause), one by one, and testing at each step to see what is causing the data to be filtered out.

Comment: that's worked fine without where clause and the join was done perfectly..@SlimsGhost

Comment: @htiru - so the join works ok, that's good. Now, if you add individual pieces of the WHERE clause back (one by one), you should be able to see why the data you want to return is getting filtered out. It should be just a process of elimination, followed by figuring out why the problem filter is not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, your parameters are by the same name as the columns definitely will cause some confusion. I would rename with some sort of prefix just to differentiate them, such as "parmCompanyID", "parmPackageID", etc.

Next, Since you are always starting with the letter, and CONDITIONALLY to the company and package, I have defaulted to a JOIN to company and package tables respectively on the ID column that would be their natural join.

Now, on to your criteria.  To get results based on only those you actually provided data for, what is that condition.  If you don't put in a company ID, you dont care and get all of them.

IF you DO put in a value for the company, you only want those that QUALIFY.  So, the JOIN is always based on the ID, but your where can add the EXTRA criteria.  If you are providing a string of IDs, then if the length of the string is 0 (nothing), then always return TRUE, yes include the company.  If the length is > 0 (something provided), then return true ONLY when that ID is in the list.

Similar application for your other criteria.  Something like

```
select 
      l.RefNo, 
      l.LetterDate, 
      l.CompanyID, 
      l.Subject,
      Case LetterType 
           When 1 then 'PSK'
           When 2 then c.CompanyCode End As FromCompany,
      Case LetterType
           When 1 then c.CompanyCode
           When 2 then 'PSK' End As ToCompany,
      c.CompanyCode,
      p.PackageID
   from 
      tblletter l,
         JOIN tblcompany c
            ON l.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
         JOIN tblpackage p 
            ON l.PackageID = p.PackageID
   where 
      CASE WHEN LENGTH( LTRIM( parmCompanyID )) = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.CompanyID LIKE '%' + LTRIM(parmCompanyID) + '%' end

      AND
      CASE WHEN LENGTH( LTRIM( parmPackageID )) = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.PackageID LIKE '%' + LTRIM(parmPackageID) + '%' end

      AND
      CASE WHEN LENGTH( LTRIM( parmSubject )) = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.Subject LIKE '%' + LTRIM(parmSubject) + '%' end
```

**FEEDBACK**

Maybe due to LTRIM() instead of a FULL TRIM(). If your parameters have leading spaces, your wild-card match would be something like '%[space][space]something%' and might not find as expected. But the context of the query should work unless the entries in the letter table are NOT always associated with a given company and/or package which would make it fail instead of LEFT-JOINs being used.

Also, if the value you are providing is a SINGLE ID for a company or package, then you shouldn't be using LIKE anyhow... you might need to change to...

```
   where 
      CASE WHEN parmCompanyID = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.CompanyID = parmCompanyID end

      AND
      CASE WHEN parmPackageID = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.PackageID = parmPackageID end

      AND
      CASE WHEN LENGTH( LTRIM( parmSubject )) = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.Subject LIKE '%' + LTRIM(parmSubject) + '%' end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @DRapp ... but '%' this is not working in mysql.. and i tested this query but still getting empty result..

Comment: @htiru, sorry delay response.  See revised answer.

Comment: i am sorry to say like still not working this with single input value instead with all the input values ` where 
      CASE WHEN 35 = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.CompanyID = 35 end

      AND
      CASE WHEN 11 = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.PackageID = 11 end

      AND
      CASE WHEN LENGTH( LTRIM( 4 )) = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE l.Subject LIKE LTRIM('sand') end`

Comment: @htiru, can you edit your existing question, go to the end of it and edit with some actual samples of the values you are trying to simulate processing with... single, multiple, string values?  what...  Appreciate it.